# How to build a wx.TreeControl with a list of file paths?

Tags: user-interface, wxpython

I want to create a TreeControl which will be a side panel containing filenames of images. How can I generate a tree with a list of file paths for the wx.treeControl?

Example of  file paths

C:\Program Files\Windows Sidebar\Gadgets\Weather.Gadget\images\120DPI\(120DPI)alertIcon.png

C:\Program Files\Windows Sidebar\Gadgets\Weather.Gadget\images\120DPI\(120DPI)grayStateIcon.png

C:\Program Files\Windows Sidebar\Gadgets\Weather.Gadget\images\120DPI\(120DPI)greenStateIcon.png

C:\Program Files\Windows Sidebar\Gadgets\Weather.Gadget\images\120DPI\(120DPI)notConnectedStateIcon.png

C:\Program Files\Windows Sidebar\Gadgets\Weather.Gadget\images\144DPI\(144DPI)alertIcon.png

I want to be able to put these into a directory tree using the wx.TreeControl

Comment: As in a node for each folder, or a node for each full path?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use the GenericDirCtrl or maybe the MultiDirDialog? If you really want to do your own thing, then this silly example should get you started:

```
import glob
import os
import wx

########################################################################
class MyTreeCtrl(wx.TreeCtrl):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.TreeCtrl.__init__(self, parent)


########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        path = r'C:\Users\mdriscoll\Documents'
        paths = glob.glob(path + "/*")

        self.tree = MyTreeCtrl(self)

        isz = (16,16)
        il = wx.ImageList(isz[0], isz[1])
        fldridx = il.Add(wx.ArtProvider_GetBitmap(wx.ART_FOLDER, 
                                                  wx.ART_OTHER, isz))
        fldropenidx = il.Add(wx.ArtProvider_GetBitmap(wx.ART_FILE_OPEN,
                                                      wx.ART_OTHER, isz))
        self.tree.SetImageList(il)

        self.root = self.tree.AddRoot(os.path.basename(path))
        self.tree.SetPyData(self.root, None)
        self.tree.SetItemImage(self.root, fldridx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
        self.tree.SetItemImage(self.root, fldropenidx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Expanded)

        for item in paths:
            if os.path.isdir(item):
                child = self.tree.AppendItem(self.root, os.path.basename(item))
                self.tree.SetPyData(child, None)
                self.tree.SetItemImage(child, fldridx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
                self.tree.SetItemImage(child, fldropenidx, wx.TreeItemIcon_Expanded)
        self.tree.Expand(self.root)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.tree, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(None, title="TreeCtrl Example")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```